# Why would a rincon provide more reliable water?

Tags: hydrology, water

I am reading a book that argues that the Ancestral Puebloans settled along the rincons, or nooks, along the canyon walls, because that was where water was reliable. I can't understand the argument, as I think the canyon floor would be the place where water from every rincon flowed, and therefore would be far more reliable than getting water from just one nook along the canyon wall. Is there some validity to the author's argument?

Comment: Hi. For a good answer you should provide more information about the setting, the details, with links, climate zone, time setting, available technology, etc. I have a basic grasp of Spanish but can't imagine how a corner could be used for channelling water. A narrow canyon floor is of course a perfect trap in case of heavy rain, and as such unsuitable as a living space. Otoh, rock-shelters were and are used throughout human history.

Comment: I read that the cliff dwellings were a late and temporary phenomenon, so perhaps it isn't that the rincon springs were the *best* source of water, just the only places so defensible that had *any* source of water. I think it counts as a historical or archaeological question, not an earth science question. 

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/riddles-of-the-anasazi-85274508/